# MS Access query to filter duplicates with criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, criteria

I have 2 tables, 1Poolwaitingexchange and VA05(ZRAX) as shown in the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN9tM.png

I need [Vcat] from VA05(ZRAX) and the relationship between the 2 tables is from both [Material Code]->[Description1] and [Cust PO] -> [PO Number] (also show in link)

The only issue is, for every [Material Code] & [Cust PO], there might be duplicates with different [Vcat] meaning all the fields are the same except for [Vcat] and I want the record with the lowest Vcat but not zero.

Eg. If the duplicate records have [Vcat] 0, 1, 2, 3, I want to choose the record that shows [Vcat] as 1.

If the records only have [Vcat] 0, I want it to show the record with [Vcat] as 0

and If [Vcat] is blank, return the record with [Vcat] blank.

The only unique record is the [Notif#] from table 1 and I have tried a lot of different approaches such as group by [Notif#], first for every duplicate field and MIN for [Vcat] but i just can't get the values i want.

My SQL knowledge is non-existant and I do a lot of trial and error I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

Comment: Please show current data, any SQL attempts, and desired results. Textual explanation is difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

You have three cases which you can `UNION` together. Someone would be able no doubt to come up with a single `SELECT` that does all three with `IFF`s and `OR`s but you might find the `UNION` approach easier to follow, especially if you don't know SQL.

I've changed some names for my own convenience and I have used `-999` because I avoid nulls:

```
SELECT p.Material_Code, p.Cust_PO, 1 AS VCat
  FROM Pool p
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM VARAX v
                 WHERE v.Material_Code = p.Material_Code
                       AND v.Cust_PO = p.Cust_PO
                       AND v.Vcat > 0 )
UNION
SELECT p.Material_Code, p.Cust_PO, 0 AS VCat
  FROM Pool p
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM VARAX v
                 WHERE v.Material_Code = p.Material_Code
                       AND v.Cust_PO = p.Cust_PO
                       AND v.Vcat = 0 )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                          FROM VARAX v
                         WHERE v.Material_Code = p.Material_Code
                               AND v.Cust_PO = p.Cust_PO
                               AND v.Vcat > 0 )
UNION
SELECT p.Material_Code, p.Cust_PO, -999 AS VCat
  FROM Pool p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                    FROM VARAX v
                   WHERE v.Material_Code = p.Material_Code
                         AND v.Cust_PO = p.Cust_PO );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want something like this. Unfortunately I don't have the ability to test my Access syntax at the moment. (I'm also assuming that "blank" is actually null. Please clarify the datatype of `Vcat` if not.)

```
select
    pwe.[Cust PO], pwe.[Part Number],
    switch(
        not isnull(min(switch(Vcat between 1 and 3, Vcat))),
          min(switch(Vcat between 1 and 3, Vcat))
        min(Vcat) = 0, 0,  true, null
    ) as Vcat
from
   1Poolwaitingexchange as pwe inner join VA05 as va
       on va.[PO Number] = pwe.[Cust PO] and va.Description = pwe.[Part Number]
group by pwe.[Cust PO], pwe.[Part Number]
```

You're right that my logic was originally bad. A minimum of zero was always going to supercede the legit values between 1 and 3. The modified version handles that by using logic that treats values outside that range as nulls and so they can be disregarded by the `min` aggregate.

You could get away with the slightly shorter versions below. All three share a common English interpretation: "Is there a value between 1 and 3? Then return the smallest one." I think the latter two read better but I don't know if you'll ever add other values that could break them. Since I don't know the nature of `Vcat`s and how they might change, I'll leave that to you.

```
    switch(
        max(Vcat) > 0, min(switch(Vcat between 1 and 3, Vcat))
        min(Vcat) = 0, 0,
        true, null
    ) as Vcat

    switch(
        max(Vcat) between 1 and 3, min(switch(Vcat between 1 and 3, Vcat))
        min(Vcat) = 0, 0,
        true, null
    ) as Vcat
```

Comment: The datatype of Vcat is Number. When I run this query I get the following error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'case
When min(Vcat)........ else null
end'.

Comment: Try `switch()`'. Not sure why I wrote that since I knew Access doesn't use `case`.

Comment: I tried writing a specific query just to filter out the duplicates in my VA05(ZRAX) table with the `switch()` criteria but all the values returned to me is NULL.

`SELECT [VA05(ZRAX)].[PO Number], [VA05(ZRAX)].Description, Switch(Min(Vcat) Between 1 And 3,Min(Vcat),Min(Vcat)=0,0,True,Null) AS Vcata
FROM [VA05(ZRAX)]
GROUP BY [VA05(ZRAX)].[PO Number], [VA05(ZRAX)].Description;`

do you have any insight as to why might be the case?

Comment: @Andrew I don't know. But try changing the `null` in the third value to   `99` or something to figure out if that's where the nulls are coming from.

Comment: @Andrew It would also help your debugging to add column `min(Vcat)` alongside the other results.

Comment: An issue when using the current switch function is that if Vcat has 0 and 3 it immediately selects the 0. I assume that is because of the first `min(Vcat)` I tried inserting the field, `[VA05(ZRAX)].Vcat between 1 and 3, min(Vcat)` but an error pops up

Comment: @Andrew I think I fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining with VA05(ZRAX) directly, try joining on query results of the rows in VA05(ZRAX) grouped the way you want.  You can do that with two subqueries grouping for the min value with and without the zeroes.

So you'll have another query named qry_va05zrax_toPool_min as

```
select 
[po number], description, 
vcatmin:min(vcat)
from VA05(ZRAX)
group by 
[po number],description
```

and qry_va05zrax_toPool_minGT0:

```
select 
[po number], description, 
vcatminGT0:min(vcat)
from VA05(ZRAX)
group by 
[po number],description
having vcat > 0
```

and a third one on both of those like:

```
select
[po number], description, vcatVal:iif(vcatminGT0 is not null, vcatminGT0,iif(vcatmin is not null, 0, null) )
from
1poolWaitingExchange p left outer join
qry_va05zrax_toPool_min m on
p.[po number] = m.[po number] and
p.description = m.description left outer join
qry_va05zrax_toPool_minGT0 z on
p.[po number] = z.[po number] and
p.description = z.description
```

Comment: I understand the methods to do this and I like the idea behind it as well. However, the results I want in the first query is not just min(Vcat) but say if Vcat has 0, 1, 2, I want the results as 1. If Vcat has only 0, then the result is 0.

Min(Vcat) gives the lowest record no matter what so it doesn't quite fit the results i need

Comment: try the updated answer, you can do it with two subqueries determining the two min values, one with and one without the zeroes.